# Remove non repeating objects from array by object property name

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have array of objects and i want to remove objects which not repeating by property of name.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Storage Capacity",
        "value": "64GB"
    },
    {
        "name": "Manufacturer Color",
        "value": "Black / Red / White / Green / Purpule"
    },
    {
        "name": "Carrier",
        "value": "Unlocked"
    },
    {
        "name": "Carrier",
        "value": "AT&T"
    },
    {
        "name": "Brand",
        "value": "Apple"
    },
    {
        "name": "MPN",
        "value": "NA"
    },
    {
        "name": "Model",
        "value": "Iphone 11"
    },
    {
        "name": "Color",
        "value": "Black"
    },
    {
        "name": "Color",
        "value": "White"
    },
    {
        "name": "Storage Capacity",
        "value": "128GB"
    },
]
```

final result must be array of objects only with name : color, storage capacity, carrier

Comment: color has appear twice,why it should in the final result?

Comment: @flyingfox because there are multiple colors and i need values. but i don't need objects which only appears once by property 'name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Array.reduce()` to calcuate the appear count of each name,then using `Array.filter()` to remove the uncessary data.

```
// calcuate the appearance of each name
let dmap = data.reduce((a,{name}) => {
  a[name] = (a[name]??0) + 1
  return a
},{})

// filter the appear count
let result = data.filter(d => dmap[d.name] > 1)
console.log(result)
```

```js
let data = [
    {
        "name": "Storage Capacity",
        "value": "64GB"
    },
    {
        "name": "Manufacturer Color",
        "value": "Black / Red / White / Green / Purpule"
    },
    {
        "name": "Carrier",
        "value": "Unlocked"
    },
    {
        "name": "Carrier",
        "value": "AT&T"
    },
    {
        "name": "Brand",
        "value": "Apple"
    },
    {
        "name": "MPN",
        "value": "NA"
    },
    {
        "name": "Model",
        "value": "Iphone 11"
    },
    {
        "name": "Color",
        "value": "Black"
    },
    {
        "name": "Color",
        "value": "White"
    },
    {
        "name": "Storage Capacity",
        "value": "128GB"
    },
]

let dmap = data.reduce((a,{name}) => {
  a[name] = (a[name]??0) + 1
  return a
},{})

let result = data.filter(d => dmap[d.name] > 1)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this :

```js
var values = [
    {
        "name": "Storage Capacity",
        "value": "64GB"
    },
    {
        "name": "Manufacturer Color",
        "value": "Black / Red / White / Green / Purpule"
    },
    {
        "name": "Carrier",
        "value": "Unlocked"
    },
    {
        "name": "Carrier",
        "value": "AT&T"
    },
    {
        "name": "Brand",
        "value": "Apple"
    },
    {
        "name": "MPN",
        "value": "NA"
    },
    {
        "name": "Model",
        "value": "Iphone 11"
    },
    {
        "name": "Color",
        "value": "Black"
    },
    {
        "name": "Color",
        "value": "White"
    },
    {
        "name": "Storage Capacity",
        "value": "128GB"
    },
];

var names = values.map(function(item){ return item.name });
let duplicated_names = names.filter((item, index) => names.indexOf(item) !== index)
let result = [];
for(let row of values) {
      if (duplicated_names.includes(row.name)) {
        result.push(row);
      }
  }
console.log(result);
```